# Using If statements in a class definition

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there any way to define class properties using If statements with a public variable already declared?

Let's i have a class defined like this:

```
Public Class SomeDude
     Property strName As String
     Property datBirth As Date
End Class
```

Is there anyway to have sth like this:

```
Public Class SomeDude
     Property strName As String
     If strPublicVariable = "foo" then
          Property datBirth As Date
     Else
          Property strBirth As String
     End If
End Class
```

Comment: That's not possible and wouldn't make sense because how could the compiler process that based on a variable that wouldn't be set until run time? If you're trying to store a date of birth then it should be a `Date` regardless. If you have a `String` as input then parse it before setting the property and if you need a `String` for display then format it.

Comment: You can use conditional compilation to have the compiler do different things based on a constant but that constant is set in the project properties, not in code, and the type of the property would then be set for that built assembly.

Comment: Thanks. It's somehow what i found here and there.
I guess one solution is to declare the class as this:
```Public Class SomeDude
     Property strName As String
     Property datBirth As Date
     Property strBirth As String
End Class```

and then use if statements whereever i need it...

Comment: In this specific case, you might declare two properties and have one of them get and set the other, i.e. the `String` property setter parses the value and sets the `Date` property setter. That would still be silly though.

Comment: @8oris `what i found here and there` I doubt it. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with such syntax? Why store a date as a string *at all*? You can always format the actual date any way you like.

Comment: @8oris type prefixes are a bad idea too, discouraged since the late 1990s. They made sense in C where you didn't know what type a pointer actually was, but no sense in object oriented languages and certainly not in object APIs, web services and JSON documents. A Property is part of a class's API, it's used for serialization and JSON generation. Intellisense will tell you what the type of each property is and the compiler will throw errors if you try to mix incompatible types. Types change too, which shouldn't affect the property names. You may want to change DateTime to DateOnly for example

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : my application is connected to a mysql database where date fields are declared as Varchar instead of datetime. These fields will be reformated but we can deploy the app easily so it has to deal with the two format regarding the app version.

Comment: Then fix the serious database bug

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : Ok, thanks for the advice but it's not my call unfortunately. ^^

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : regarding prefixing with type, i read all and its contrary online in some "Good Practice Guide". Personnaly, i find the code more-readable and usable and, IMHO, these 3 letters in front of a variable don't hamper the code.

Comment: Only if you are willing to go to court or can get in writing that this was not your responsibility. You have no idea what that field contains, no idea what the strings in there mean - what is 04/07/2022? April 7? Or July 4? People have ended up in [serious trouble](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html) due to such bugs.

Comment: No, this is terrible practice - why do you think no MS tutorials or Github repos use it? VB6 devs used it because they had to pass `object` everywhere. And trying to cover up the date bug is worse. Fix the critical bug (ie serious made critical due to the attempt at coverup)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I can't agree more but this app is not that ciritical. I totally get your point but like i said: it's not my call. :)

Comment: And yet, you now have to spill the bud into the code. You shouldn't even be looking at that anyway - the ORM can load the date and convert it to a string. Even if you don't use an ORM, there's no reason to keep a string field around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You must have to declare type.

or you have to use Directives to make it compile time
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/directives/if-then-else-directives